# Move ndarray data into another one

Tags: python, numpy

I want to move the np.array with 3 rows and 2 columns into a.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,2))
a[:,1] = np.array([[3],[3],[3]])
```

but some errors there.

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
 could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)
```

Would you tell me how to move it?

Comment: `a[:,1]` is a 1 dimensional slice of `a`. You are trying to move a 2d array into a 1d slice, hence the error.

Comment: @ dermen Thank you. I see. Would you tell me how to move the 2d array data into a[ : , 1] ?

Comment: Change the 2d array into a 1d one!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,2))
a[:,1] = np.array([3,3,3])
```